# Using aggregate function but don't want to group by the specific column

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

When I do:

```
select firstpartno,count(firstpartno) 
from dbo.vw_Split4 
group by firstpartno
```

it works well.

Mow I want two new columns `nMaleCount` , `nFemaleCount`. These will be the count(firstpartno) for M and for F respectively. But the count forces me to group by Sex, which I don't want. I want to do all these and have my four columns but group by firstpartno only. Please help on this please!

vw_Split4 is as below:

```
firstpartno     Sex
     1           M
     2           F
     2           F
     3           M
     5           M
     2           M
```

I want it to be  like this after:

```
firstpartno     Sex     nMaleCount     nFemaleCount
     1           M
     2           F
     2           F
     3           M
     5           M
     2           M
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can SUM on a CASE statement:

```
select firstpartno
      ,count(firstpartno)
      ,sum(case when sex = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) nMaleCount
  from dbo.vw_Split4 
 group by firstpartno
```

Comment: Thank you so much Karl. This works well! Exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you'd rather do:

```
SELECT firstpartno, Sex, COUNT(firstpartno)
GROUP BY firstpartno, Sex
```

Unless you want to divide the count for M and F to 2 columns for some reason...